# How to keep logged in on both web:ports?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies, session, private-browsing

I have two instances of qBittorrent with different profiles running normally without issue on the same machine.

[image]

Although profiles are stored separately, both configurations are using the same usernames and passwords. And they are remembered in the browser.

[image]

When trying to log in both services (`http://unconditionallove:8181` and `http://unconditionallove:8282`)

the former session immediately ends when the latter
connects.

[image]

If I log in `http://unconditionallove:8282` in private browsering mode. I can keep both sessions successfully.

Is it possible to keep logged in on both ports?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be that the cookies that are being set are by host name only. What if you access one of the instances by IP address?

Comment: @Mokubai Yeah, the 'Domain' field of the cookie is the only hostname and no other fields are containing the port info. Is that the reason the browser denies to accept both cookies? Trying IP address will work along with the hostname method.

Comment: Alternatively, use a separate browser, or use a browser that supports multiple profiles, such as chrome, vivalde, etc... You can have one profile open for one instance, and the other for the other, both at the same time.

Comment: Yes, with the hostname the same then the second host is overwriting the cookies for the first and essentially the first connection starts sending garbage and is immediately dropped by the host.

Comment: @LPChip The browser profiles are different from qBittorrent profiles. Multiple instances of qBittorrent are running, with different qBittorrent settings. This is achieved because the settings are store in different profile folders. See the values after --profile in the picture. The cookies using the same hostnames should be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your behaviour suggests that gBittorrent does not expect multiple servers on the same host. This is kind of normal for web servers.

When you log in to the second server the cookies for `unconditionallove` (rather than `unconditionallove:8282`) are updated and any "session" information that the first connection was using becomes invalid.

There are a few ways around this

1. Use `unconditionallove` for one host and the IP address for the second. This would give two unique sets of cookies, one for `unconditionallove` and one for `<IP address>`
2. Add another name via your computer (not server) hosts file which points to the same IP address but with a different name. On Windows your `hosts` file (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) you would add

   ```
   127.0.0.1 unconditionallove
   127.0.0.1 unconditionallove2
   ```

   (replace `127.0.0.1` with the IP Address of your server)
3. If you need to connect to both servers from multiple machines then set up a DNS server on your network or computer that does this naming for you. Otherwise you will have to edit the hosts file for every computer.